# Trunk setup between netgear switches

Tags: home-networking

I have 2 Netgear switches (GS724Tv4, GS724TP), which are 10m apart. The remote switch has the NAS attached, and I would like to increase bandwidth between the switches by connecting Ports 23 and 24 of both switches and set them up as a trunk. How do I do that exactly?

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: Well, vlan 1 cannot be edited. Therefore I assume I have to setup a second vlan and set ports 23 and 24 to tagged. All other ports are u tagged. Is that correct?